# %C4%83 converted to ? using URLDecoder in java

Tags: javascript

I have tried a simple web application using JAVA 8, Tomcat 8 and to send the request to server from web application using ajax. while decoding , I am getting ?.

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
   alert("called");
   
    
    $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'add', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : {
            
                  str:encodeURIComponent($ ('#str2').val())
            } ,// our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                        encode          : true,
                        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        });
});
 });
```

```html
<form id="ff" action="add" method="post" enctype="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input name="str" id="str2" multiline="true" value="This TextBox will allow the user to enter multiple lines of text." style="width:100%;height:120px"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit"></input></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" id="button2" value="Submit1"></input></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Server side

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println( URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("str"),"UTF-8"));
}
```

I have tried the String from client is

Acest TextBox va permite utilizatorului să introducă mai multe rânduri de text.

Comment: If I run standalone program using main, it is printing correctly. but in web it is behaving wierd

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the method below?

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
String str= request.getParameter("str");
System.out.println(str);
```

I would like to know what you will get.

---

Would you try the JavaScript below for me?

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
  alert("called");


    $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'add', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : JSON.stringify({ str:$('#str2').val() }) ,// our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: If I use encodeURIComponent($ ('#str2').val()) then Acest%20TextBox%20va%20permite%20utilizatorului%20s%C4%83%20introduc%C4%83%20mai%20multe%20r%C3%A2nduri%20de%20text.

Comment: If I do not use encodeURIComponent then Acest TextBox va permite utilizatorului s? introduc? mai multe rânduri de text

Comment: I tried JSON.stringify still same issue before setting request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") and after request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  {"str":"Acest TextBox va permite utilizatorului s? introduc? mai multe rânduri de text."}

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code in eclipse oxygen and STS and it didn't work. I have created a war and deployed on tomcat 8 and tomcat 9 and it worked without any issue. So probably there might be some settings in eclipse oxygen or STS. As the same thing worked under eclipse mars.

I found the solution. In Run configuration in sts or eclipse we have to set encoding (common->encoding->Other (UTF-8).